# Pseudocode to PHP

Tags: php, function, pseudocode

This is what I'm working with:

```
FUNCTION findHighest(dataArray returns array)
BEGIN
    FOR items in dataArray
        IF highest[1] is already set
            IF value > highest[1]
                highest[0] ← key
                highest[1] ← value
            END IF
        ELSE
            highest[0] ← key
            highest[1] ← value
        END IF
    END FOR
    RETURN highest
END
```

I need to change the pseudo-code so it takes in two arrays as parameters, one called dateArray and one called rainArray.
Then change the FOR so that it’s a normal FOR loop with an incrementing index called $i

And then I need to make it into a PHP function

I know this is a lot but I would really appreciate some help

Thank you in advance

Comment: you need to make an attempt. If you cannot achieve it, add some demo data, current/tried code and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a PHP implementation for the pseudo code, with the changes. However, it is not specified what `rainArray` is used for, so this is as close as it could get given the specs.

```
function findHighest(array $dateArray, array $rainArray)
{
    $highest = [];

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($dateArray); $i++) {

        if (isset($highest[1])) {

            if ($dateArray[$i] > $highest[1]) {

                $highest[0] = $i;
                $highest[1] = $dateArray[$i];
            }
        } else {

            $highest[0] = $i;
            $highest[1] = $dateArray[$i]
        }
    }

    return $highest;
}
```